# Combine multiple rules into one rule

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following rule:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FromNumber).NotEmpty().GreaterThan(0).When(x => x.NumbersRequired).WithState(x => MyErrorEnum.FromNumberRequired);
```

The property `FromNumber` is of type `int?`. The problem with the above is that `CustomState` is only set for `GreaterThan`. If the value is null or 0, `CustomState` is null.

If I change the above to the following the rule still works as expected:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FromNumber ?? 0).GreaterThan(0).When(x => x.NumbersRequired).WithState(x => MyErrorEnum.FromNumberRequired);
```

But is there a better way to combine both rules into one rule instead of using the null conditional operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons to use several predefined validation rules instead of one custom, are:

1. have properly generated client-side validation attributes in MVC
2. have different error messages (by using default error messages, or `WithMessage` method)

**1-st** reason isn't your case, because you use `When` condition — it cancels any client-side attributes generation for affected rules.

**2-nd** not critical for your case, because you can combine error messages into one, if you need to do this.

So you can combine your rules into single predicate rule:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FromNumber)
    .Must(x => x != null && x > 0)
    .When(x => x.NumbersRequired)
    .WithState(x => MyErrorEnum.FromNumberRequired);
```

**P.S.** Syntax like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FromNumber ?? 0)
```

not only changes validated value, but also can change referrenced property name in unpredictable way `when constructing dictionary of errors`. Use property chain expression only in `RuleFor` / `RuleForEach` methods. If you prefer to use complex expressions like this — do not forget to specify actual property name in `.WithName()` method.

Comment: How would I implement this rule: `RuleFor(x => x.ToNumber).NotEmpty().GreaterThan(x => x.FromNumber)`?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono use another overload with access to model: `RuleFor(x => x.ToNumber).Muxt((model, x) => x != null && x > model.FromNumber);`